# Dynamically change the from address in sender profile (unverified)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email2case, sender-authentication-package, transactional-messaging-api, reply-mail-management

Our customer service team receives an email notification every time the website contact form is submitted. This is now sent via Marketing Cloud's transactional messaging API.

The email is 'from' a specific sender profile but as these notifications are being used for email-to-case functionality in Salesforce Service Cloud, the case is always created against our sending email address. Previously, a transactional email service was used that would use the customer's email address as the 'from' address.

Am I correct in understanding there is no way to replicate this in Marketing Cloud as while it's possible to dynamically populate the from email address, this has to be verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you can use Dynamic Sender Profile for that case.
When the code runs it validates the email address and if it appears to be unverified, then the fallback value is used, which cannot be unverified ([documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_may_2020_fallback_address.htm&type=5)).
Therefore, the email addresses that you would need to use in DSP have to be either within the Sender Authentication Package domain or added to the "[From Address Management](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_from_address_and_domain_verification_configuration_checklist.htm&type=5)" page in the Setup.